# How to filter query by related privileges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write select that filters users by containing at least one permission with `display = 1`. My tables looks like the following:

```
User:
-id
-user_email_id

UserGroupRelation:
-id
-user_id
-user_email_id
-user_group_id

UserGroupPermission
-id
-permission_id
-display(bool)
-user_group_id
```

One user, can have multiple groups and permissions that are assigned to group. I would like to select all users that are in groups with at least one permission that have display set to 1. How would I do it?

That is what I tried and it didn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM User as u
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    UserGroupRelation as ugr on ugr.user_id = u.id and ugr.user_email_id = u.user_email_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    UserGroupPermission as ugp on ugp.user_group_id = ugr.user_group_id
WHERE
    ugp.display = 1
```

I think the problem is that User has multiple group relations and groups have multiple permissions. Maybe should I use another select in FROM clause?

**Sample data:**

```
  User:
    {id=1, user_email_id=1}, 
    {id=2, user_email_id=2}

  UserGroupRelation: 
    {id-1, user_group_id=1, user_id=1, user_email_id=1}, 
    {id=2, usergroup_id=2, user_id=2, user_email_id=2}

  UsergroupPermission: 
    {id=1, permission_id=1, display=1, user_group_id=1}, 
    {id=2, permission_id=1, display=0, user_group_id=2}
```

Result should return only user that has id=1 because he is connected to group_id = 1 which has permission with display=1, user with id 2 is not in result because he has permission that has display= 0. It is simple example because user can have multiple groups and group can have multiple permissions but only one that h as display = 1 is required to be in the result

Comment: I have been trying to use left outer join on UserGroupRelation and UserGroupPermission and then where display = 1 but i had unexpected results

Comment: Are you by chance missing a join statement before UserGroupRelation?

Comment: I think tables joined correctly but probably I need use some subquery with count on Permission rows that have display=1 or something like that and then WHERE count > 0

Comment: The SQL you posted in the question is missing the words `left outer join` between `users as u` and `UserGroupRelation ` - I think. You've tried to join 2 tables, but have only used the join syntax once. I'm assuming its a type?

Comment: oh yeah it is a typo I have rewritten it instead of pasting

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected output? I'm not sure I'm following your need and doing so might help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your SELECT is simply badly formatted. Try running the following in place of what you have shared above:

```
SELECT * FROM @User AS u
INNER JOIN UserGroupRelation AS ugr 
    ON ugr.[user_id] = u.id AND ugr.user_email_id = u.user_email_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserGroupPermission AS ugp
    ON ugp.user_group_id = ugr.user_group_id
WHERE
    ugp.display = 1;
```

If I run this in my test environment against your sample data, I recevie the following resultset:

```
+----+---------------+----+---------+---------------+---------------+----+---------------+---------+---------------+
| id | user_email_id | id | user_id | user_email_id | user_group_id | id | permission_id | display | user_group_id |
+----+---------------+----+---------+---------------+---------------+----+---------------+---------+---------------+
|  1 |             1 |  1 |       1 |             1 |             1 |  1 |             1 |       1 |             1 |
+----+---------------+----+---------+---------------+---------------+----+---------------+---------+---------------+
```

On a side note, I would change `LEFT OUTER JOIN UserGroupPermission AS ugp` to `INNER JOIN UserGroupPermission AS ugp` given that "display" is required in your expected resultset.

Comment: I do not need joined tables to be in my result, all I need it to filter the User by having atleast 1 privilege that has display set to 1